# Filtrar conteúdo abaixo da diagonal principal de uma matriz

Tags: java

Para pegar o conteúdo que está abaixo da diagonal principal de uma matriz seriam os elementos nas posições em que a linha é maior que a coluna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Para pegar o conteúdo que está abaixo da diagonal principal de uma matriz seriam os elementos nas posições em que a linha é maior que a coluna?

Sim.